# Can't run a shell script every 24 hours

Tags: shell, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have written a shell script that runs some commands. I have added a logic to run this script once every 24 hours. But it runs once and then doesn't run.
The script is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  cd /home/ubuntu/;
  DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`;
  aws s3 cp --recursive "/home/ubuntu/" s3://bucket_name/$DATE/;
  rm -r -f ./*;
  # sleep 24 hours
  sleep $((24 * 60 * 60))
done
```

Why does it not run once every 24 hours ? I do not get any errors when the script runs. The copy takes about 10 mins.

Comment: Use [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: How long does it take to do the copy?  If it takes n hours, I would expect it to start every n + 24 hours.

Comment: What error do you get?  Do you by chance have aws auth tokens stored in /home/ubuntu...which is being deleted in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: I do not get any error when this runs. The copy takes 10 mins to run.

Comment: You commented on one answer that you don't *want* to use cron. Any particular reason for that? (I'm smelling a X-Y problem...) -- How exactly do you run the script? In a shell? What's the exact invocation? What happens to the shell once you've run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The good practice is to protect your script againt multirunning.

   In this case, you can be sure that only 1 instance is running.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   LOCKFILE=/tmp/block_file

   if ( set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$LOCKFILE") 2> /dev/null;
   then
       trap 'rm -f "$LOCKFILE"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT

   while true; do
     cd /home/ubuntu/;
     DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`;
     aws s3 cp --recursive "/home/ubuntu/" s3://bucket_name/$DATE/;
     rm -r -f ./*;
     # sleep 24 hours
     sleep $((24 * 60 * 60))
   done

   rm -f "$LOCKFILE"
      trap - INT TERM EXIT

   else
      echo "Warning. Script is already running!"
      echo "Block by PID  $(cat $LOCKFILE) ."
      exit
   fi
   ```
2. You can run a script immune to hangups.

   `nohup` is a UNIX utility that runs the specified command ignoring communication loss signals (SIGHUP). Thus, the script will continue to work in the background even after the user logs out.

   ```
   nohup ./yourscript.sh
   ```

   The created file `/tmp/block_file` will safe runned script against multirunning. To complete it press `ctrl+c` or run `kill -11 pidofyourscript` in terminal, in this way `/tmp/block_file` will be deleted.
   The output of script puts on file `nohup.out`.

   To run in background (preferred way):

   ```
   nohup ./yourscript.sh &
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is probably killed due to inactivity, or when you exit the shell. The proper way to do this is use cron, as @Christian.K mentioned. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: I want to do it in a way so as to not use cron. Is there a way to do it without using cron.

Comment: Make sure your script runs as a deamon process, run it with &.